# How do I get my navigation bar to cover the whole page?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am fairly new to this kind of stuff. I just want my nav bar to cover the page from side to side instead of having the white spaces on both sides and the top.

Here is my CSS

```
nav ul {list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3E3F43;}

nav li {float: left;}

nav li a {display: block;
       color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;}

li a:hover{background-color: #7559A6;}


Here is my HTML

<nav>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Does your `<nav>` element have a margin or something? You just address the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove the default margin from the `body`

```
 body {
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Then:

**CSS tables**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3E3F43;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  display: table-cell
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #7559A6;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3E3F43;
  display: flex;
}
nav li {
  flex:1;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #7559A6;
}
```

```html
<nav>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

give your nav an id

```
   <nav id=nav">
```

And set it's width to 100%

```
    #nav{
    width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css

```
nav{ position: absolute; width: 100%;left: 0;top: 0;}
```